# Subscribe from C++ external file

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi!,

I am a new user of Gazebo and maybe this is a trivial question but I was trying to subscribe a topic from a c++ file, so I basically followed the custom messages tutorial. If I have a plugin and want to subscribe a topic the line that I need is:

```
subJointStates = nodeController->Subscribe("~/robot/JointState",&UpdateJointState,this);
```

When I tried to subscribe from the c++ file, I can't use `"this"`, since I don't have a class, I have tried replacing "this" with a boolean value,  because the declaration of Subscribe wants a boolean.

I tried both of them

```
subJointStates = nodeController->Subscribe("~/robot/JointState",&UpdateJointState,true);
subJointStates = nodeController->Subscribe("~/robot/JointState",&UpdateJointState,false);
```

But, looks like it's not working, should I try a different way to subscribe from a C++ External File?

Thank you,

Victor

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1409/subscribe-from-c++-external-file/) by [vcparedesc](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/183/vcparedesc/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

My mistake!!, sorry, I realized that `"~/robot/JointState"` calls

```
`gazebo/<node_parent_name>/robot/JointState`
```

However, I was in another node, so `"~/robot/JointState"` was pointing to:

```
`gazebo/<another_node_name>/robot/JointState`
```

Just in case, if some beginner as me gets confused by a simple error.

---

Originally posted by [vcparedesc](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/183/vcparedesc/) with karma: 43 on 2013-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bharadwaj Ramesh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/154/bharadwaj-ramesh/) on 2013-05-07**:
HI, I am trying to write a simple subscriber. I am pretty much a beginner with Gazebo and with C++. Here is my question.
http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2676/simple-subscribing-plugin/

Can you please help me with it. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks